# PHP - Simple IF ... ELSE IF... producing unexpected results, educate me?

Tags: php, if-statement

I am having trouble with a simple peice of php code.

I am working with 2 product pricing tiers. These are based on whether a user has logged in, or not.

*If a user is not logged in, and the first price is empty; then the price is price1. If not, it is price1.*

This works perfectly fine.

*If a user is logged in, and the first price is empty; then the price is price1. If not, it is price2.*

This is the way it should work, but what actually happens is this:

*If a user is logged in, and the first price is empty; then the price is **0**. If not, it is price2.*

Why is my code producing this effect?

```
if (!userIsLoggedIn())
{
    if (empty($prPrice2))
    {
        $prPrice = $prPrice1;
    }
    else
    {
        $prPrice = $prPrice1;
    }
} else if (userIsLoggedIn())
{
    if (empty($prPrice2))
    {
        $prPrice = $prPrice1;
    }
    else
    {
        $prPrice = $prPrice2;
    }
} else 
{
    $prPrice = $prPrice1;
}
```

If anyone has any suggestions that could help me to resolve this issue, it would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you!

@Pekka, it is fairly complicated. I simply would like this to happen:

```
product 1 -> price 1 = 1.00
product 1 -> price 2 = 0.00
product 2 -> price 1 = 1.00
product 2 -> price 2 = 0.80
```

If a user is logged in but the price2 field is empty, then the price variable will be price1. if not, then it will be price 2.

On the other hand, if a user is not logged in but the price2 field is empty, then the price variable will be price1. if not, then it will be price 1.

Comment: This doesn't make sense: First you are checking for whether a user is logged in, then for whether a user is *not* logged in, then for whether a user is *not not* logged in.  So if the user *is* logged in, the 1st and 3rd block will always trigger. What do you want to do in the end? Whre do `$proPrice1` and `$proPrice2` come from? This looks like a bit of a mess, what I do in such cases is delete everything and start again

Comment: The first embedded `if` block appears to produce the same effect either way (`empty()` or not).

Comment: userIsLoggedIn() is also called twice which may produce unexpected results, btw.

Comment: @Pekka See edit to my post please...

Comment: @Kevin Thank you, I did not think of that. But the function is coded well enough to operate under circumstances like this.

Comment: @BlackberryFan: Please clean up your algorithm requirements. You are saying all kind of things that contradict them selfs. Make sure you have the **exact** requirements clear before you write them down for us, to have us help you.

Comment: @fireeyedboy It was not all kinds of things, merely one simple typo. the 2 was meant to be a 1. Sorry to all for any inconvieniance cause.

Comment: @BlackberryFan: Then read your own question very carefully again, and correct the typo's! How are we supposed to understand the requirements if there are typo's in the essential requirements. For instance: `then the price is price1. If not, it is price1.` So here it will always be `price1` then?! Then in your edited section: `then the price variable will be price1. if not, then it will be price 1.` So again, it will always be `price1` then?! I could go on and on about your question. Please clean it up. It will probably help yourself understand the problem better as well.

Comment: @fireeyedboy please see my comments to fvu, the way that is was explained is the way that it is supposed to happen. I know that the code is wrong, that is the reason for this post. Thank you for your input in anycase.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You code is overly complicated and contains some odd constructions.  This is an equivalent but simplified version, but check the comment I added on the first else....

```
if (!userIsLoggedIn())
{
    if (empty($prPrice2))
    {
        $prPrice = $prPrice1;
    }
    else
    {
        $prPrice = $prPrice1;  // this is highly suspicious...
    }
} else {    // user is logged or not, no need to recheck that boolean var
    if (empty($prPrice2))
    {
        $prPrice = $prPrice1;
    }
    else
    {
        $prPrice = $prPrice2;
    }
}
```

a slightly fancier way of expressing the same condition with the ternary statement (example is equivalent to else block of the outer if:

```
$prPrice = (empty($prPrice2)) ? $prPrice1 : $prPrice2;
```

EDIT

Assuming that there is a way to differentiate between accountholders that haven't logged in and users without accounts, your need to handle that in an outer condition, like this:

```
if ($UserHasAnAccount) {  
// but i don't understand (yet) how you'd know that at this point
    if (userIsLoggedIn()) {  // the price logic described before
        ....
    } else {
        ....
    }
} else {  // unknown user, price1
    $prPrice = $prPrice1;
}
```

Comment: Please see my edit in the op. It is like this, because people that do not hold physical accounts with our store, will only see cash prices. Those that do hold accounts, can log in and are able to see the second tier pricing. Fishy yes, but this is part of the wholesale industry. Thank you for the input, will give the code a try!

Comment: I'm confused here - how do you differentiate not logged in accountholders and non accountholders?  A cookie or some other means?

Comment: Precisely so, the cookie is renewed on a monthly basis. Would you have a better solution?

Comment: @blackberry okay, in that case, if the presence of the cookie is reflected in the state of the variable `$UserHasAnAccount` in the edit above, that code should do what you want - the key is to handle known/unknown and logged/not logged in 2 levels, not in 1 as you tried.

Comment: UserIsLoggedIn is a function, that queries a session variable that is set once the users credentials are matched against mysql database, based on the user account number, password and account type.

Comment: Thank you, that does make sense. Now for the million dollar question... why is it so hard for everone else to understand that? Again, thanks for the help, will try this out now!

Comment: @blackberry no idea, maybe because a long time ago I had to code a pricing scheme that was even more twisted? :-)

Answer (score 5):

The way you explained the rules was a bit confusing. You should be able to modify the below code to fit:

```
if (userIsLoggedIn()) {
    $prPrice = !empty($prPrice2) ? $prPrice2 : $prPrice1;
} else {
    $prPrice = !empty($prPrice1) ? $prPrice1 : $prPrice2;
}
```

Comment: I have edited my op, please see the changes in the first instance. I will give this a try in a bit! Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

The code is in contradiction with the algorithm you described.

You told:

> If a user is not logged in and the first price is empty, then the
>   price is price1. If not, it is price2. If a user is logged in and the
>   first price is empty, then the price is price1. If not, it is price2.

So, in fact, the algorithm should do exactly the same thing whether the user is logged in or not.

In your code, it's also very strange:

You have three conditions:

1. user is not logged in
2. user is logged in
3. other

The user is logged in or it's not logged in. I don't see any other possibility.

And also, the following lines:

```
if (empty($prPrice2))
{
    $prPrice = $prPrice1;
}
else
{
    $prPrice = $prPrice1;
}
```

could be reduced to

```
$prPrice = $prPrice1;
```

since you're doing the same operation in the two code blocks.

Comment: Thank you, I have edited my op, it was a simple typo in the first instance. Please see it.

Comment: You're still checking price2 in your code is the "user logged in" branch, whereas your algorithm description talks about checking the first price. And in the "user not logged in" branch, you still have *then the price is price1. If not, it is price1*, which makes the "empty" test completely unnecessary.

Answer (score 1):

```
else 
{
    $prPrice = $prPrice1;
}
```

You can't reach this condition because as I understand `userIsLoggedIn` is boolean and it may happen only two conditions: when userIsLoggedIn is true and when it false.
You wrote that

> If a user is not logged in and the first price is empty, then the price is price1. If not, it is price2.

But in you code this happens:

> If a user is not logged in and the **second** price is empty, then the price is price1. If not, it is **price1 too**.

Also in the condition userIsLoggedIn you wrote that

> If a user is logged in **and the first price is empty**

But in your code you check if the second price is empty.